# Can it is possible to allow user for multiple selection of file in storage access framework..?

Tags: android, provider

After clicking on a button i am getting the content from provider

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(i, REQUESTCODE);
```

now i want to allow user for multiple selection is it possible.?

Comment: you display your content inside a listview or so ? then just use the longclick function from listview

Comment: according to you i have to bring all data from all directory into a listview which will be headache and user will be get irritated by scrolling for selecting file. is there any another way available ?

Comment: you need to clarify your question, for using multiple selections you typically use a listview, because you need to show multiple items a user can select, or what did you want ??

Comment: storage access framework allows the multiple selection? i need it because it allow user to select directly from the directory.

Comment: don't know the details about this framework, but as seen from google drive and so on, it should be possible, just depends how you present the result, as ContentProvider gives you Cursor, you can display the results in a ListView GridView etc. and there you have the option to select multiple, but actions still have to be done one be one

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 17):

Don't know if you solved your problem, but here's how I implemented a multiple selection with the Storage Access Framework

```
    Intent filePickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    filePickerIntent.setType("*/*");
    filePickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    startActivityForResult(filePickerIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

In the Activity Result method, you just need to iterate the ClipData in the Intent parameter

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        if(data != null)
        {
            ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
            for(int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++)
            {
                ClipData.Item path = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                Log.i("Path:",path.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To select multiple files in the Storage Access Framework Activity UI, just hold press any item and the multi selection will activate.

Comment: Application crashes! Also I was able to select only one file at once. After selecting only file I pressed OK and the chooser intent came again. This time the app crashed!

Comment: clipdata will be null if only one file is clicked.
Check if clipdata is null then proceed for multiple file select.
if null then:  `data.getData()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need:

```
val PICK_JSON_FILES = 2
private fun pickFilesFromDevice() {
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
    addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
    type = "application/json"
}
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_JSON_FILES)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, 
resultData: Intent?) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData)

if (requestCode == PICK_JSON_FILES  && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    // Check if multiple files were selected
    val clipData = resultData?.clipData
    if (clipData != null) {
        for (i in 0 until clipData.itemCount) {
            val uri = clipData.getItemAt(i).uri
            // Use the uri
        }
    } else {
        // If only one file was selected, handle it here
        val uri = resultData?.data
        // Use the uri
    }
  }
}
```

Note: the type of files I am looking for here is JSON, change it for the type you want.